# How to disable Pydio password?

Tags: php, ajax, pydio

I found this question on stack and I need to do the same thing but with their newer product Pydio. Any thoughts? The same type of config file is not present??

> @user962284: Im using ajaxplorer on a local server and I dont want to use the user
>   authentication each time I open my browser (write the user and
>   password)
>
> ajaxplorer is created with php and ajax, and I think modifying the
>   source code is possible to disable the user authentication, or at
>   least use a blank password
>
> but, what lines of the code are necessary to modify?

The answer for  this query was to:

> ENABLE_USERS :  Toggle user accounts on/off. If set to 0, the
>   application is not protected! ALLOW_GUEST_BROWSING : Toggle whether
>   guests (unauthenticated users) can browse your files.

**How do I do this in Pydio??**

Comment: Why did you copy the text instead of adding the link?

Comment: @MohitJain  just easier, you can read it all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable from GUI of Pydio >> Settings >> Application Core >> Authentication >> Sele